# Determining what a forloop must execute (and how many times) using an input variable

Tags: php, for-loop

Is it possible make a forloop execute the code you've entered in a textbox on a html page?

I've tried doing this:

```
<?php

$codejwz = $_POST["codejwz"];
$aantalkeiren = $_POST["aantalkeiren"];

function forloop($aantalkeren, $code){

  for($i=0; $i<$aantalkeren; $i++){
  $code;
  }
}

forloop($aantalkeiren, $codejwz);


 ?>
```

My input for "codejwz" was `echo "test"` and for "aantalkeiren" it was 40.

However, (to my surprise,) I didn't get any error messages. Just a blank page. 
Could you help me out in this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/function.eval.php) but it's very dangerous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval()` to execute code that's in a variable.

```
for($i=0; $i<$aantalkeren; $i++){
  eval($code);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a parse error now: unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';' in eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: `$codejwz` needs to end with `;` to be a valid statement.

Comment: So enter `echo "test";` into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `create_function` function to turn the `$code` into a function, then call the function in the loop.

Replace your loop and function call with this:

```
$innerFunc = create_function ("" , $codejwz);

for($i=0; $i<$aantalkeren; $i++){
  $innerFunc();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, but i still get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in  : runtime-created function on line 1

Comment: Make sure your input is valid PHP